# Logarithm help with order of growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am doing an order of growth question that involves logarithms. I have an expression and I need to determine which function controls the growth. I have come across a question that I cannot see how they got the order of growth to be that answer. The question is below.

$$\text{Find the order of growth of }2^{\log(n^2)} + 2^{\log(n)^2}.$$

They are saying that the order of growth is $n^{log(n)}$. I don't know how they got this answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use Latex. Did you mean $2^{\log(n^2)}$

Answer (score 0):

$$y = 2^{\log(n^2)} + 2^{\log(n)^2}$$
$$y = (2^{\log(n)})^2 + (2^{\log(n)})^{log(n)}$$

Substitute $log(n) = \frac{log_2(n)}{log_2{10}}$ and for less cluttering I'm replacing $\frac{1}{log_2{10}}$ by $k$.

Hence, $log(n) = k.log_2{n}$

$$y = (2^{\log_2(n)})^{2k} + (2^{\log_2(n)})^{k.{log(n)}}$$
$$y = n^{2k} + n^{k.{log(n)}}$$

Substitute $k$ where $k = \frac{1}{log_2{10}} = 0.30111$

$$y = n^{0.60222} + n^{0.30111.{log(n)}}$$

Now I think you can calculate the growth from reduced expression.

Comment: Converting to log base 10 is excessive clutter.

Comment: It seems that the person who asked the question has not much experience with these kinds of question, hence I elaborated the answer.

Comment: Busy work.  Show how the second summanf reduces to the given answer.  That is math instead pencil pushing.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the order of growth is the larger (2nd) of the two summands.
Now simplify that to arrive at the desired conclustion,